# Why do left and right switch when direction is reversed?

Tags: applications, plane-curves, orientation

If I make a left turn during a trip, it becomes a right turn on my way back.  Why is this?

Comment: Is that the new tag-guideline? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Because turning around to make the trip back corresponds to applying a reflection. A reflection is an orientation inverting operation, so left interchanges with right.

Comment: Hmmm, is it really fair to call a 180 degree turn a reflection?

Comment: @ErickWong, yes, once that 180 degree turn is taken in order to trace your steps back. It is no longer a turn, but rather a reflection. Locally, you do the same, but globally things are very different.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\gamma:(0,1)\to\Bbb R^2,$$
be a smooth parametrized curve such that $\gamma'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$ (you don't stop during $(0,1)$). Then, for each $t$ there are two unit vectors $N(t)$ orthogonal to $\gamma'(t)$, only one of which makes $\{\gamma'(t),N(t)\}$ an oriented basis for $\Bbb R^2$. This choice of $N(t)$ gives a smooth vector field along $\gamma$ telling us the left direction. Now, you turn left at $t_0$ if and only if
$$\gamma''(t_0)\cdot N(t_0)>0.$$
Taking the reverse curve
$$\bar{\gamma}:(0,1)\to\Bbb R^2,\quad\bar{\gamma}(t)=\gamma(1-t)$$
and repeating the process of generating a unit orthogonal oriented vector field $\bar{N}$ for this curve, you will find $\bar{\gamma}(1-t_0)=\gamma(t_0)$ and
$$\bar{\gamma}''(1-t_0)\cdot \bar{N}(1-t_0)<0,$$
meaning you now turn right at that time.